# Preserve tab-indent when pasting from MS Word into WYSIWYG

Tags: internet-explorer, wysiwyg, paste

I have a system, built 2005, which uses TinyMCE 2.0.5.1. In this version, when you paste text from MS Word (tested in version 2000, 2003, 2007 and 2010) into Internet Explorer (tested version 6,7,8 - but breaks in 9), you can pick up tab characters like this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
       mode : "textareas",
       editor_selector : "mceEditor",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,zoom,flash,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,pasteword,forecolor,code",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    /*theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "",*/
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    /*theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,*/
    force_p_newlines : true,
    force_br_newlines : false,
    apply_source_formatting : true,
    remove_linebreaks : false,
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
    paste_convert_headers_to_strong : true,
    fix_content_duplication : false,
    content_css : "http://autosystem.streatcontrol.com/mce.css",
    paste_insert_word_content_callback : "findtabs"
    });



    function findtabs(type, content) {


        if (type == "before"){
          content = content.replace(/(<SPAN style="mso-tab-count)/gi,'@tab@$1');
        }
        if (type="after"){
          content = content.replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'');
        }

        return content;
    }
```

This seems to break in IE9 and I need to urgently replace this system. What I need is:

A Browser/ WYSIWYG combination that supports picking up tab characters when text is pasted. Due to the nature of the application and number of users, we can specify the browser to be used (we have in the past)